# Conditional execution of 'getInitialProps' in Next.js

Tags: react-hooks, next.js

I have global state management using `useContext` and `useReducer` I want to check whether the user is authenticated or not. to do so, what occurred to me, was to check inside `getInitialProps` in this way:

```
DashboardPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const [globalState, dispatch] = useContext(STORE.storeContext);
  let auth = globalState.isAuthed
  if (!auth) {
    auth = axiox.get('/authenticateThisUser');
  } 
  return {
    auth,
  }
}
```

However, when I execute this snippet, it throws *`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`*. how can I use `useContext` inside `getInitialProps`?

What I'm looking for is a way to prevent components from sending redundant auth requests to
 the server.

It would be great if there were some methods to conditionally execute `getInitialProps`
like this:

```
if(globalState.isAuthed){
    //dont execute getInitialProps of this component
}else {
    //execute getInitialProps of this component
}
```

Comment: react hooks can only be used inside Functional components and not inside functions or loops or blocks.Read documentation for more info.. Here you are creating const [globalState, dispatch] = useContext(STORE.storeContext); Context hook inside a funciton and not Functional Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I wanted to accomplish could be done using code below:

```
DashboardPage.getInitialProps = async ({ req, query, asPath }) => {

    // only in server-side
    if (req) {
        const userUrl = `http://localhost:3000${userConfig.ROUTES.user.getUser}`;
        const isMeUrl = `http://localhost:3000${userConfig.ROUTES.isMe}`;
        const result = await axios.all([axios.get(isMeUrl), axios.get(userUrl)]);

        return {
            me: result[0].data.payload,
            user: result[1].data.payload,
        };
     }
     // only in client-side
     // since we've done authenticating, it is set in the global state management
     // therefore, no need to send any request to the auth API endpoint.
     return {};

};
```

This way we make sure auth requests will be sent only on the server-side (first request) and prevent the component from redundant requests to be sent.